# Proof of congruency

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I practice with some easy tasks and I can't solve one of them. I know that:

$$
a\equiv b \pmod n\\
a\equiv b \pmod{n^\prime}\\
\gcd(n, n^\prime)=1
$$

I need to show that $a\equiv b \pmod{nn^\prime}$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$a\equiv b \mod n \implies a-b=k_1 n$$

$$a\equiv b \mod n' \implies a-b=k_2 n'$$

for some integers $k_1$,$k_2$.  If $k_1 n = a-b =k_2 n'$ and $gcd(n, n')=1$ then $k_1$ is a multiple of $n'$ and $k_2$ is a multiple of $n$, so $a-b = k_3 nn'$ for some integer $k_3=k_1/n'=k_2/n$. And

$$a-b=k_3 nn' \implies a\equiv b \mod nn'. $$

Comment: How did you deduce that, by Euclid's lemma, unique factorization, properties of gcds or lcms? It is *essential* to say what properties you use in order to judge if the proof is correct.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\rm\ \ \ gcd(n',n)=1,\ \ n'\:|\:n\,(a\!-\!b)/n\:\Rightarrow\:n'\:|\:(a\!-\!b)/n\:\Rightarrow\: nn'\:|\:a\!-\!b\ \ $ by Euclid's Lemma.

Alternatively $\rm\:\ n,n'\:|\:a\!-\!b\:\Rightarrow\:lcm(n,n')\:|\:a\!-\!b,\ $ but $\rm\:lcm(n,n')=nn'\ $ if $\rm\ gcd(n,n') = 1.$